# I need help getting the filters to work with soundcloud api in Ruby

Tags: ruby, api, pagination, soundcloud, partitioning

Whenever I add the value of ":limit", ":offset", and ":linked_partitioning => 1" to my api call the filters seem to stop working. How can I get them to work while still getting ?

```
page_size = 600

tracks = client.get('/tracks', :q => 'music', :limit => page_size, :offset => 200, :linked_partitioning => 1)

tracks.each {|t| puts t.title}
```

This is the error I get:

[image]

If I replace "tracks.each {|t| puts t.title}..." with just..

```
puts tracks
```

or..

```
puts tracks.next_href
```

I'll get the results, but with NO FILTERS.. if I use any filters like

```
tracks.each {|t| puts t.id}
```

or any other one it'll get a method error like before...any ideas?
What I'm trying to get as a result is being able to get tracks by a filter and then be able to get the next page of results using the same filter and so on. Please help. Thanks. :)

Comment: what `get` method returns you in `tracks` ? can you show that.

Comment: idk what you mean...you want the results? its the 200 tracks with no filters...meaning a looong list with the titles, id's, links, users, plus a lot of excess info, when I only need certain info from the results... @jonsnow

Comment: At this info, all looks fine. may more context will help.

Comment: what kind of context? because everything is as you see it... @jonsnow

Comment: if the api call won't use filters, is there a way to select what i need from the results that contain all the filter options in the results as a whole. meaning i could maybe write a manual function to extract what i need? @jonsnow

Comment: and does it work for you when you try it? @jonsnow

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what youre asking I think youre not diving deep enough into the object Soundcloud returns.  With your no method error, its saying that you are trying to call .title on an array like this, [some info].title. You might have to step down another level in the data structure.  I had a lot of issues with the linked_partitioning, try removing that and iterating though the array like you have been doing. If you get the results youre looking for I would try double iterating through the object.

Hope this helps